# How to add margins to the grid view through CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


#section1{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#section2{
 margin-right: 10px;
}

div div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div div div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#Chicken {
  background-color: #EF9A9A;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#Beef {
  background-color: #F44336;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
}

#Sushi {
  background-color: #CDDC39;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Assignment solution for module 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="section1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div id="Chicken">Chicken</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div id="Beef">Beef</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
      <div id="Sushi">Sushi</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I add margins between the boxes in the large screen view  Can anybody see how can it be done. I have tried to add the margin between boxes in the large screen view but it simply doesn't show, It just breaks the line and shows in the next line.
It must also view correctly like specified in other sizes too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#section1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#section2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div div div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#Chicken {
  background-color: #EF9A9A;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#Beef {
  background-color: #F44336;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
}

#Sushi {
  background-color: #CDDC39;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Assignment solution for module 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="section1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div id="Chicken">Chicken</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div id="Beef">Beef</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
      <div id="Sushi">Sushi</div>
      <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, concectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got some relavant code from one community for your post,find this below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.main {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```